# Git Revert or Reset on published Commits

Tags: git, reset, revert

I have a development branch, another dev just pushed a commit to the branch in github. I need to rollback or revert to a prior commit, that was pushed to Github on 6-11-16 (a1c8cda)

```
-------------------------------------
334a6d6 - Pushed on 6-13-16
a1c8cda - Pushed on 6-11-16
-------------------------------------
```

I would like to retain the history, and if the other two developers need to pull this rollback that is ok. 
I am reading the differences between revert and reset and quite honestly am getting confused.

Comment: Check out this answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21718540/3357393

Comment: ProgrammerDan can you put that as an answer and i can accept it?

Comment: Ah, an "only link" answer is frowned on in general :). Just give some recognition to the folks over in that linked question and all will be well. I assume it was helpful to you?

Comment: ahhh ok. but yes the link was exactly what i needed, that answered my questions and confusion, so thank you again